# Insert bookmark to next line in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have some lines bookmarked. I want insert a bookmark to next line of these lines.

[image: http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/5674/nextbookmark.png]

I recorded this macro on Notepad++ but I don't understand because doesn't work well:

```
F2
down arrow
ctrl+F2
```

This simply combination give me errors, is there a solution?

This is the raw macro code:

[image: http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/5002/macrocode.png]

In this case I record 3 times **F2-down arrow-ctrl+F2**.

But I don't want to record the number of lines that are marked (21,59,63), I want simply apply the macro.

Comment: Note: Notepad++ questions are just as on-topic here as any other dev tool.

Answer (score 2):

i solve this problem using AutoHotKey..i record a script and edit it with this text:

```
WinWait, *new  2 - Notepad++, 
IfWinNotActive, *new  2 - Notepad++, , WinActivate, *new  2 - Notepad++, 
Sleep, 100
Send, {F2}{DOWN}{CTRLDOWN}{F2}{CTRLUP}
```

**`new  2` is the name of my current opened notepad++ window

**    `Send, {F2}{DOWN}{CTRLDOWN}{F2}{CTRLUP}` is the keyboard command required to create a bookmark after the above bookmark. If i copy many times *Send, {F2}{DOWN}{CTRLDOWN}{F2}{CTRLUP}* I get the desired result